# Classify domain in $\Bbb R^3$ as open/closed/bounded/connected

Tags: calculus

If I have a function:

$$f(x,y,z) = \frac{{\sqrt {\ln (1 + {z^2})} }}{{\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| + \sqrt {xy - 1} }}$$

And I need to classify its domain as open/closed/bounded/connected.

My thoughts:
The only restrictions are that xy>1, so the function is bounded. Since it doesnt contain its boundary points, it is not closed. And I think it is also open? How do I tell if the domain is connected?

Comment: Welcome on MES! See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function  What is the domain here? A drawing may be interesting, notice $z$ is not constrained at all, so you can see first what happens in the plane $z=0$. What is the curve $xy=1$?

Comment: hint: what does $xy\geq 1$ look like in three dimensions? (you're wrong that this region is bounded. it does have a boundary, though...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. $xy \gt 1$ is the only required stipulation. $f$ is defined everywhere else.

[image]

This is the graph for $xy = 1$ in $\Bbb R^3$. Any values below(or above as you may picture it) the graph (or the two hoods ) satisfies $xy \gt 1$. So $D(f)$ is not bounded. Since given any $M \gt 0$ there is $(x, y, z) \in D(f)$ such that $ x, y, z \gt \text{Max}\{M, 1\}  \implies |(x, y, z)| \gt M $. It can be similarly proven that $D(f)$ is not bounded below. You are right about it being open. But maybe a little more justification is needed. It is clearly not connected. I do not know your definition for connectedness. According to mine $D(f)$ is disconnected since there are two open sets $A = \{(x, y, z) \ | \ x \gt 0 \land y \gt 0 \}$ and $B = \{(x, y, z) \ | \ x \lt 0 \land y \lt 0 \}$ such that $A \cap D(f)$ and $B \cap D(f)$ are disjoint, non-empty and have union $D(f)$.

Comment: thanks! and yep, that is our definition for connectedness as well